# Android: An error occurred while trying to get the sha-256 fingerprint of the keystore file

Tags: android, android-keystore, applinks, android-app-signing

I'm trying to create an App link but the App links assistant keeps throwing the below error in Step 3 (Associate website) while generating the assetlinks.json.

> An error occurred while trying to get the sha-256 fingerprint of the
> keystore file. Please make sure that your keystore file is correct.

[image]

I have tried both the options but getting the same error:

1. Signing config - debug
2. Keystore file - Created a new keystore from Build > Generate signed Bundle/Apk > Apk > Create New

Am I missing something? I'm on Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 3
Is there a way to create the JSON file without using the App links assistant?

Comment: "Is there a way to create the JSON file without using the App links assistant?" -- it's just a JSON file. I used a text editor. `keytool` can give you the hash to use.

Comment: If your keystore has a password, the tool will be not able to automatically generate the JSON file. You may run `keytool -list -v -keystore <your keystore file>` and enter the password.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use online tool for generating this json: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Or create it yourself, it's really really simple file, sample: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started#quick-usage-example

Comment: Thanks, wasted an hour on the tool :)

Answer (score 3):

If you already have an app in the play store, just go to the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/console/)

And then go to: **Release > Setup > App integrity**.

You can find the json content at the end of the "App signing" tab.